# Creating a custom ImageList class by extended image property

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, gdi+, imagelist

I would like to replace my existing ImageLists with custom imagelists.

```
Public Class clsImageList

    Public Images As New List(Of clsImageItem)

    Public Sub Add(ByVal uGUID As String, ByRef uImage As Image)

        Dim nItem As New clsImageItem(uImage, uGUID)

        Images.Add(nItem)

    End Sub
    Public Function Image(ByVal uIndex As Integer) As Image

        Return Images.Item(uIndex).Image

    End Function

End Class

Public Class clsImageItem

    Public ReadOnly Property [Image] As Image
    Private _sGUID As String

    Public Sub New(uImage As Image, uGUID As String)

        Image = uImage
        _sGUID = uGUID

    End Sub

End Class
```

I am trying to make my class compatible with the .NET ImageList so that I don't have to change much code.

```
            Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(SomeBitmap)
                g.DrawImage(il.Images(myIndex), 0, 0, 256, 256)
            End Using
```

The error I'm getting is "There are no overloads for this function.".

I do understand this error, it can't render my clsImageItem, but I wonder if I could perhaps extend the Graphics to accept my clsImageItem.

Do I have to replace

```
.il.Images(myIndex)
```

by

```
.il.Images(myIndex).Image
```

or is there a simpler / more convinient way?

Comment: While I have no Idea about what you are trying to do, you can pass `il.Images(myIndex).Image`, also you can create an extension method to accept your `clsImageItem`.

Comment: why don´t you use your Image function? `il.Image(myIndex)`. Additionally you could think about changing the List(Of clsImageItem) to `Dictionary(string, clsImageItem)` where string is the GUID. Thus you could access any image via GUID (if required).

Comment: I can appreciate what you are trying to do, but most of that code serves no purpose.  The `_sGUID` is private so it wont ever act as like a Key; if it *was* accessible, you will have to use linq to find an image by Key.  The `clsImageList` serves no purpose since the Image collection is public.   Dipping into the List is no different than using the Image function.  Instead of trying to make something sort of like the ImageList, make something that is more finely tuned to what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `il.Images(myIndex).Image` that refers to the `Images` list in `il`.

You can use `il.Image(myIndex)` that refers to the `Image` function in `il`.

> I wonder if I could perhaps extend the Graphics to accept my clsImageItem?

Yes you can create an extension method that accepts your `clsImageItem` class.

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module GraphicsExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Sub DrawImage(ByVal g As Graphics, c As clsImageItem, x As Integer, y As Integer , w As Integer, h As integer)
        g.DrawImage(c.Image, x, y, w, h)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Then to use this overload, import the module that holds the extension method and then you can write:

```
g.DrawImage(il.Images(myIndex), 0, 0, 256, 256)
```

**More information about Extension Methods**

> Extension methods enable developers to add custom functionality to
>   data types that are already defined without creating a new derived
>   type. Extension methods make it possible to write a method that can be
>   called as if it were an instance method of the existing type.

- [Extension Methods (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/extension-methods?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [How to: Write an Extension Method (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-write-an-extension-method?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)